# Assign each element in an array to a variable using PHP.

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with unknown information. I want to get each element and assign it to a variable so I can use it elsewhere.

This works but it only gets the first element.

```
function firstElement($foo,$m='k') {
                    foreach ($foo as $k=>$v){
                    return $$m;
                }
}

$firstKey=firstElement($foo);
$firstVal=firstElement($foo,'v');
```

Comment: I don't want to echo the array. I just want all the elements assigned to variables. Thanks!

Comment: Consider `extract()` built-in function instead

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? What's your expected result? Add a couple more details please.

Comment: That is the function of [`extract()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), though if they are in an array, perhaps they are related and _belong_ in an array?

Comment: I want each element to be assigned to it's own variable. I'm unclear what to 'grab' after using extract().

Comment: *extract()* does exactly what you would want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the extract() PHP function. 
If you want to doit yourself:

Remove the "return" statement from there. Once you "return" a value, the foreach and the entire functions stops.

Answer (score 1):

The extract() function will pull out each array key and assign the value to a variable.  If the key is, for example, 'color', then it will name the new variable $color and assign the value from the array key to it.

```
extract($foo);
```

Comment: If I use extract(); what are the variables? Where are the elements? I'm not interested in printing the array nor echoing. I just want each element in a variable.

Comment: Let's say we have an array called $contactinfo and it has keys of 'phone', 'firstname', and 'lastname'.  So one of them would look like $contactinfo['firstname'].  If you use extract($contactinfo) the keys will not exist as $phone, $firstname, $lastname.  If $contactinfo['phone'] was 555-555-5555 now $phone == 555-555-555 . It makes each key be a new variable's name with the previous value still attached to it, but just not in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

To find out what the name was assigned to each element I used **print_r($foo);**

This gave me:

```
array("a" => "blah", "b" => "blah")
```

Then I used extract

```
extract($foo);

//echo "$a";
//echo "$b";
```

Comment: @ Reneee Rose-Perry.  Above, you commented and said this, "I'm not interested in printing the array nor echoing. I just want each element in a variable." Yet in your own answer you've printed the array.  Please ask your question more clearly.  You are also not answering your own question as written because you did not make it clear that you never knew so much as the array key names.